# PHP error in Netbeans IDE

Tags: php, netbeans

I am currently using a PHP 5 along with Netbeans IDE to create a login page.

However Netbeans seems to not understand the codes that I have added into the console box.

The error originates from the "echo "....." line.

The codes are as follows:

```
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
 echo "Thank You for registering {$first_name}! Your username is {$username}";
 echo "<a href="index.php"> Click here </a> to Login";
}
}
?>
```

The errors shown are:

-Syntax error: Unexpected : Index
-Syntax error: Unexpected : String

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from

```
 echo "<a href="index.php"> Click here </a> to Login";
```

to

```
 echo "<a href=\"index.php\"> Click here </a> to Login";
```

You have to escape those "" or use '' like so:

```
 echo '<a href="index.php"> Click here </a> to Login';
```

But watch out on that first echo you MUST use "" since you are using variables in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 echo "Thank You for registering {$first_name}! Your username is {$username}",
            '<a href="index.php"> Click here </a> to Login';

or:

        echo sprintf("Thank You for registering %s! Your username is %s\n<a href='index.php'> Click here </a> to Login",
                        $first_name, $username);
```